# I cant link this file with HREF. All others files link fine

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to get a Button element to link to one of my html files/pages. It can link to any other html page. This is an odd issue I cant seem to solve. The file it will not link to my file, writeReview.html but seems to work with other files. Fixed HTMl has been added.

```html
    <button href="PlaceHolder">Write A Review</button>
```

```html
<div class="buttonOne">
  <a href="./writeReview.html">Write A Review</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What happens instead?

Comment: Buttons doesn't support `href`

Comment: I can link any file using a HREF except one file. I have restarted my code editer and tested with other files

Comment: Buttons Dont support HREF? Then How would I link to the page then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: Please explain further what you **want** to achieve, and what you've tried to achieve this. "I cant link this file" sounds pretty vague - what does that mean?

Comment: buttons are not for linking pages. Linking other pages (resourcess) require an anchor. Buttons are for firing scripts like JS

Comment: create an `a` tag and style it with the same CSS as a button, use the Dev tools to see what the browser has defined for CSS button styling. Don't forget the `:hover` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `href` attribute for `<button>` elements.

If you want to link somewhere, use an `<a>` element.

`<button>` elements are (depending on their `type` attribute) either for dealing with `<form>`s or for having JavaScript hooked into. They are not links.

Comment: Thankyou.  Code is now <div class="">
  <a href="./writeReview.html">Write A Review</a>
</div>